# How can I solve this Tensorflow using and installing Error?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I had used tensorflow before this time.Now,tensorflow is installed but it cannot be imported.Moreover,it cannot be installed again.What happened in tensorflow?I searched many solutions for this error but I cannot find.When tensorflow is installed with pip,this error appears.

```
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\python.exe C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\Scripts\pip-script.py install tensorfow'
```

And when it is installed with anaconda,it can be installed,but cannot be imported,"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'".How can I solve this trouble to reuse tensorflow without reinstalling anaconda ,please help me.Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall and reinstall the pip:

```
python -m pip uninstall pip

python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

or update pip:

```
python -m pip install -upgrade pip
```

Comment: I did this also.But it does not work.